# How to modify a string respecting line breaks and line beginning?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I'm trying to add quotation marks to the elements of a list which happens to be a single string separated by commas and line breaks, to then split the string at the commas *respecting line breaks*.

Assume we have a string like this:

```
string = "a,b,c,d
         e,f,g,h"
```

Since the string contains a single element, to add quotations I've tried adding `"` around the commas and after the line breaks, with `StringReplace[string, {"," -> "\",\"", "\n" -> "\"\n"}]`, but the result is not quite what I expect:

```
"a","b","c","d"
         e","f","g","h"
```

How can I add quotations to all elements separated by commas, including these at the beginning of a line or at a line break? The result being something like:

```
"a","b","c","d"
"e","f","g","h"
```

Additionally, how can we split the string at each comma (`,`) *while respecting the line breaks*?

If we do `split = StringSplit[string, ","]`, the result is weird:

```
a,b,c,d
         e,f,g,h
```

Specifically, `d` and `e` becomes a single element, with the line break added to it:

```
split[[4]]

"d
         e"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringReplace[string, {
  StartOfString -> "\"",
  "," -> "\",\"",
  patt : ("\n" ~~ WhitespaceCharacter ..) :> StringJoin["\"", patt, "\""],
  EndOfString -> "\""}]
```

> ```
> "a","b","c","d"
>           "e","f","g","h"
> ```

or without the brackets

```
StringReplace[string, {
  StartOfString -> "\"",
  "," -> "\",\"",
  patt : "\n" ~~ WhitespaceCharacter .. :> StringJoin["\"", patt, "\""],
  EndOfString -> "\""}]
```

> ```
> "a","b","c","d"
> "e","f","g","h"
> ```

And for splitting the string

```
Flatten[Fold[StringSplit, string, {",", "\n"}]]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d,          e, f, g, h}
> ```

or

```
Flatten[Fold[StringSplit, string, {",", "\n" ~~ WhitespaceCharacter ..}]]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}
> ```

Additional case

```
string = "two words, one\n     another, this three words"

StringRiffle[
 StringReplace[#, {StartOfString -> "\"", "," -> "\",\"", 
     patt : ("\n" ~~ WhitespaceCharacter ..) :> 
      StringJoin["\"", patt, "\""], EndOfString -> "\""}] & /@ 
  StringTrim /@ StringSplit[string, ","], ","]
```

> ```
> "two words", "one"
>      "another", "this three words"
> ```

Comment: Interesting. It works for the case I gave and most cases I've tested, but it seems to rely on white spaces, which is problematic for many cases I work with, in which I have things like `"two words, one, this three words"`, etc. In particular, it adds line breaks at white spaces.